# Using a public key in received from a C server in a Java client

Tags: java, c, cryptography, rsa

I'm having some weird problems with using a public key in a Java client. I get the public key from a C server, and I know the following:  B64Encoded, X.509 RSA key, and I should use PKCS1Padding. I have done the following so far to make sure that the data being transmitted between the client and server is correct:

1) The data content and length that are sent from the server is identical with the java client

2) Once it's B64decoded, the data and length are the same

3) I've also verified that the data is the same between a C client and the Java client, until I start to create a public key from the decoded data.

I'm running into a problem, that the Java client is sending too much data back to server after the Cipher encrypts the password. I've tried to use different methods in creating the public key object, but nothing seems to work. I either get a "**algid parse error, not a sequence**"-error, or the key is created, and I end up sending too many bytes of data (139 from Java vs 128 from the C client).
Here's the code (snipped out some irrelevant things). Everything is broken down to single try/catches, as I was trying to pinpoint the problem:

```
byte[] pk = getKeyFromServer(); // 191 bytes 
String keyString = new String(pk);
byte[] decoded = decode(keyString); // 139 bytes

try {
    keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
} catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();}

try {
    keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "IBMJCE");
} catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();}

try {
    publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
} catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();}

try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/SSL/PKCS1Padding", "IBMJCE");
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

try {
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

try {   sendEncrypted(cipher.doFinal(pwd.getBytes()));
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

The above code runs into the exception I mentioned before, and if I remove the KeySpec and KeyFactory parts, and go with the following I get to the encryption part, but then I send too much data, and the server can't decrypt it (I got the exponent from digging around).

```
java.math.BigInteger modulus = new java.math.BigInteger(decoded);
java.math.BigInteger exponent = new java.math.BigInteger("22111");

publicKey = new RSAPublicKey(modulus, exponent);
```

So I guess the question is, am I doing something totally wrong, or is there something that I should know more about what the C client is doing to the BASE64decoded public key before it uses it to encrypt, and try to replicate that? Right now I am unable to access that part :(

I've tried to use different KeySpecs, PublicKeys and paddings, but the result is always the same (though the exception might differ when I'm way off base with the KeySpec).

The communication between the server and client work well otherwise. It's just this part that uses the public key that isn't working.

**EDIT:** Just wanted to add the public key String, if that tells anything:

```
Public key from server:
MIGIAoGBAMZawVoP6mHl0xD3Epn1l4S/6Ke20ZTNLKaXyi425NwhiE7LoTysAcpx
y3i9LXLVNGpdPNtpGD3mvlNJc/HfGQQ7NQpNyKpe5EzsODb1YCbODtfmaRODDW9B
qsrE8DCxI0g8gzu3NJTrUh4NfRaSBn9HaOnBUwiyQyihq2I6MB6bAgJWXw==
```

Comment: Are you in some strange developer-unfriendly environment? Any decent IDE will tell you where an exception occurred without you having to wrap every single statement.

Comment: You do this: String keyString = new String(pk);
How is the data encoded in the return from getKeyFromServer();?  Depending on how it's encoded, new String(pk) could be mangling your data?

Comment: Marcelo: Breaking the code down to multiple try/catches is just something I like to do while doing this. I clean up stuff like that later. @nojo I've tried to decode the byte[], but when I compare that output to what I get from the C client it was different, and I ran into the same problems.

Comment: Note that String.getBytes() and the String(byte[]) constructor should never ever be used when communicating with anything other than a program that uses the default platform encoding (and the use is questionable even then). You aren't sending encoded characters back instead of bytes, are you?

Comment: BTW, if the key can be instantiated, the chances of the key being incorrect are very small indeed, its much more likely that the input or output of the Cipher.doFinal() is the culpit, or the encoding of the data after that.

Comment: One other thing: In the previous encryption related things I've done on Java, the Cipher output has been the same length as the key (128 bytes). This leads me to think that what if I have to somehow modify the base64 decoded public key I receive from the server before I create a key from it, as the length of the decoded byte[] is 139? I'm getting the feeling that I'm just throwing out all kinds of ideas here, to see if someone catches onto something that's not right here...

Comment: No, the encoding of the key *should* be larger than the key length, as it is wrapped in a DER encoded structure. You can easily verify this, the first byte will have value 30 hex (a ASN.1 DER tag for a SEQUENCE). You can use openssl parseasn1 -inform DER -in <filename> to see what is in it (after putting it in a file of course). If this does not fail you can deduct that the base 64 decoding was indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" without the "/SSL" in the middle? SSL uses a special structure if I'm not mistaken.

In addition:
The encoding is not X509 compatible! It seems that the encoding of the key is PKCS#1 and X509 uses a small wrapper around that encoding!

From PKCS#1:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

From X509EncodedKeySpec:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
   algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
   subjectPublicKey BIT STRING }
```

So you will have to add the sequence tag, length, algorithm identifier and BIT STRING tag and length in front of the data you are receiving! Weird that you could let it do anything at all.

For this specific keylength and (weird) two byte public exponent, the header would consist of the following bytes:

```
(byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x9E, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x2A,
(byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xF7, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01,
(byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x8C, (byte) 0x00,
```

Alternatively, you could also simply retrieve the two integers from the structure and create an `RSAPublicKeySpec` from those.

Comment: I've tried all kinds of cipher and keyspec variations. So many actually, that I lost count a loooong time ago :) Most of all, I've tried all the RSA-variations. I just can't figure out why the output is as long as it is. I've tested key passing from a Java server to a Java client (a very basic test), and it always worked as I thought it should (sends 128 bytes of encrypted data). Like you said, the culprit is most likely the Cipher, but I just can't figure out why :(

Comment: Hmm, I see I'm trying to explain ASN.1 encoding here, I'll try and come up with a byte[] sequence to prepend, before trying to explain that. This would however be specific for the length of the key (the modulus length) and public exponent, which is a weird two byte value. SafeNet HSM?

Comment: I did try to use the RSAPublicKeySpec, and I've tried to forgo with the X509EncodedKeySpec, but neither of those options worked. Now I just got informed, that the C-side of things has been reworked, so I'll have to see if that changes anything.